# [HTML/JS]Adding "&" before the second last word of string and hiding "&" if there is a single word in that string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am working on the UI part (HTML and JS) of a website. In that, there is a table for selecting 4 different types of products. Now, I want to display a summary at the end of the page. If the user has selected product of **Type-1** only then show the **summary as (Type-1)** else if products of **Type-1, Type-2, Type-3** as selected show summary as **(Type-1, Type-2 & Type-3)** or if products of **type 2 and 4** are selected show **(Type-2 & Type-4)**. How will I decide when to **add** the **&** and when **not to add** depending on the number of products selected and add comma after each product type but not if only a single product is selected or only two products are selected? Each product is listed in a separate drop down list and I am calling the method in javascript using the onchange() of each dropdown to know which product is selected.

Comment: how r u adding commas, are u joining an array?

Comment: Why is there the `java` tag? Is there any `java` backend?

Comment: I need to get the logic of adding commas also :)

Comment: Yes its actually a JSP page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRGC8/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Type 1" id="type_1" onchange="setType();" /> Type 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Type 2" id="type_2" onchange="setType();" /> Type 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Type 3" id="type_3" onchange="setType();" /> Type 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Type 4" id="type_4" onchange="setType();" /> Type 4<br />
<textarea id="types"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function setType() {
    var types = [];
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ) {
        var input = document.getElementById( "type_" + i );
        if ( input.checked ) {
            types.push( input.value );
        }
    }
    var textarea = document.getElementById( "types" );
    types = types.join( ", " );
    var index = types.lastIndexOf( "," );
    types = types.split( "" );
    types[ index ] = " &";
    types = types.join( "" );
    textarea.value = types;
}
```

**P.S.** I don't like `substr`

Comment: What if the user un-selects an earlier selected product, will need to remove his product from the list then

Comment: Great, thats what i was looking for. But it seems to give problem in IE.

Comment: @user2674084 for my IE 11 all works fine. What is your version?

Comment: IE 8. The target browser is mainly IE 8 and below :) Even in my chrome it works fine.

Comment: I changed "onchange" to "onclick" and it works like a charm now.

Comment: @user2674084 glad to help. P.S. i'm try to load jsFiddle in IE 7 - it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you like `substr`? :)

Comment: @Hexus I'm better work with array. Infuriates me that I can't assign any simbol to some place of string, like `var s = "123"; s[ 1 ] = "0"; //s = "123"`. I can do something like `s.replace( /^(.{1})./, "$10" );` but it's terrible and bad to understand. Better do `s = s.split(""); s[ 1 ] = "0"; s = s.join( "" );` and more clearly.

Comment: Oh wow, that's quite an annoying feature of the language that I didn't know about. I'd always assumed that if you can get an index of a string, you can also set it, but apparently not!

Answer (score 1):

If the products are in an array then you can use following code :

```
var myStringArray = [ "Type-1", "Type-2", "Type-3", "Type-4" ];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
var string = myStringArray[0];
for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {
    string += ", " + myStringArray[i];
}
string += " & " + myStringArray[myStringArray.length - 1];
```

String result will be: Type-1, Type-2, Type-3 & Type-4.

Comment: The products are not in array. How can i dynamically modify the array depending on the selection and deselection of product?

Comment: is this what you are looking for?
 function handleSelection(
    var myStringArray = new Array();
    
    $('dropdown').each(function(index){
        myStringArray.push($(this).val());
    });
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    var string = myStringArray[0];
    
    for (var i = 1; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {
        string += ", " + myStringArray[i];
    }
    string += " & " + myStringArray[myStringArray.length - 1];
    
    return string;
)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JavaScript for this and have the comma delimited list of products available, you can do a simple replacement of the last comma.

```
var summary = '(Type-1, Type-2, Type-3)'; 
var i = summary.lastIndexOf(',');
if(i > -1){
   var summary = summary.substr(0,i) + ' &' + summary.substr(i+1);
}
console.log(summary);
```

Though I would recommend using `&amp;` instead of a literal `&` if you're inserting this into the document.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this

```
function addPunctuationToList (items) {
    return items.length > 2 ? items.slice(0,-1).join(', ') + ' & ' + items.slice(-1) : items.join(' & ');
}

addPunctuationToList(['Type-1', 'Type-2', 'Type-3', 'Type-4']); // returns "Type-1, Type-2, Type-3 & Type-4"
addPunctuationToList(['Type-1', 'Type-2', 'Type-3']); // returns "Type-1, Type-2 & Type-3"
addPunctuationToList(['Type-1', 'Type-2']); // returns "Type-1 & Type-2"
addPunctuationToList(['Type-1']); // returns "Type-1"
```

**update**

to build up the items array you would do something like this

```
var items = [];

$('select').each(function (index, element) {
    if (element.value) items.push(element.value);
});

addPunctuationToList(items);
```

**update 2**

heres a working example of what i think you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/ex2zh/4/

Comment: The products are not in array like u said(var types). How can i dynamically modify the array depending on the selection and deselection of product?

Comment: what are the products exactly? what format, are they checkboxes or what? how do you even know a user selected something?

Comment: The products are listed in dropdown list. I am calling a method in java-script using the onchange()

Comment: and how will I remove that particular type if user un-selects that product

Comment: @user2674084 does my updated answer not answer your question? (try this link for a demo http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/ex2zh/3/)

Comment: but the JS methods are not called anywhere

Comment: i bound them to the onchange event, so every time the `select element` changes the array gets rebuilt, and the addPunctuationToList gets ran. you said you were binding to the onChange() right? or do you not have access to jQuery?

Comment: OK. No i don't have access to jQuery the app is like that only.

Comment: but you have not called the methods anywhere in html

Comment: @user2674084 you should not call methods inside of the html. people stopped using inline javascript events 5 years ago. is there a reason why you need to use them? (heres an example of inline events http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/ex2zh/6/). I'm going to stop answering because i dont like where the quality of the code is going.

Comment: I mean the call to the function need to be given on some event. I was not talking about inline events. Thanks